# Selenium is not got imported in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use `selenium` for web browsing and I'm getting the following - what can I do to fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "c:\apps\python25\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.35.0-py2.5.egg\selenium\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from selenium import selenium
SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined (selenium.py, line 17)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Python 2.5`? I am running selenium with no issues on `Python 2.7`

Comment: so it won't work on 2.5?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use newer version of Python to make it work. Use `Python 2.7`. `Python 2.5` doesn't supports selenium. Here's a issue regarding this:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1559